# Why does MINGW (Git Bash) say my username is the server hostname+username, and how do I change it?

Tags: mingw, git-bash, mingw-w64

I have a Windows server that I have a created a local `devops` account on. For simplicity, lets say this servers hostname is `WINDEVSRV`.  When I start Git Bash, MINGW32 says my username is literally `WINDEVSRV+devops`.  My full prompt looks like:

```
WINDEVSRV+devops@WINDEVSRV MINGW32 ~
$ pwd
/c/Users/devops
```

I have setup the `sshd` that comes with MINGW32, but in order to ssh in, I have to ssh in as `WINDEVSRV+devops`.  I want to drop the hostname, because I have to set this up for other servers, and I dont want to hardcode hostnames. However, I dont know how MINGW32 generates the username or how to change it.

To be explicit, my end goal is to be able to run `ssh devops@WINDEVSRV` and NOT `ssh WINDEVSRV+devops@WINDEVSRV`.  I dont actually care what my `$PS1` looks like.